# JMeter: JSON Path Assertions fail without any error

Tags: jmeter

Below is the error shown on failure of my test.

JMeter version: 3.2
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Value expected to be 'ptgrna9jgc1f3a77881+iamtestpass', but found 'ptgrna9jgc1f3a77881+iamtestpass'

There is a failure even if the 2 strings are exactly same. Any idea why this is happening?
PS: The tests are running as expected on a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything started working fine after switching to JMeter 3.1!

Answer (score 0):

If assertion fails - something is wrong, my expectation is that the reason is in:

- Your JSON Path Expression returns a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) and you are expecting its 1st element
- There is a leading or trailing space (or both) either in the JSON Path return value or in your expected data. Double check both using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. But the tests are running as expected on a different machine.